# Timing and speed of multiple sliding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/q3zc0ojy/2/) I have set up.

You are first confronted by three links. Each link triggers divs to slide out.

1. The link 'john smith' slides out and in at the speed we want. When it slides out the first line slides out then when that is completed the second line slides down as though coming from the first. When it slides back it does the same motion at the same speed but reverse i.e.. the second line slide back up first and then when that is completed the first line slides back to the left.
2. When you click on the work link and menu slides out in the same manner as the bio. Also there is a sub menu that slides out when on clicks on item 2.
3. When the user clicks on the contact link one line slides out.

What we need to achieve is this; when any div is open and another link is clicked on, the visible div slides back in reverse to how they slid in. We have almost achieve this, however, the code is not quite right as the divs are not sliding back in at the same speed and in the right order, they simply slide back fast. For example, if one has clicked on 'work' and the 'item 2' link, and then you select 'contact' the opened div slide back very quickly. What I need to achieve is that they slide back in reverse to how they slid out.

To attempt to make it clear, if you click on 'work' and then 'item 2' so with menus are visible and then click on work again, you will see the sub menu slides away first before the first menu. You will also notice that the items that slide up slide back down first before the divs slide back to the left. This is what needs to happen if you click on 'contact' or 'john smith' when the menus are visible.

I know this sounds very complicated and if I can answer any questions to make it clearer I will.

Thanks

```
$('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'hide'});
$('#contact-info').animate({right: 'hide'});
$('#bio-line-2').slideUp("fast");
$('#black-div, #black-credits, #igna-1-div, #igna-1-credits, #igna-2- div, #igna-2-credits, #fatal-div, #fatal-credits').fadeOut('100');
```

});

Comment: It is because of `$('#igna, #black, #igna-1, #bio-line-2').slideUp("fast");` inside `$('#contact').click(function() {`

Comment: You have to do lot's of thing for every click.

Comment: @angela, classic case for [`TimelineMax`](http://greensock.com/timelinemax). Heard of it? Can you afford a few extra KBs in your project? Would you want to see an example using your code as base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/q3zc0ojy/10/)

I finally worked out how to fix it to work how I intended, however my code is very long winded. I realise there must be a way to reduce the repetition of the code by using generic functions. I will now post the working code onto Code Review for further development.

```
$('#menu').click(function () {
if ( $('#igna-1').css('display') != 'none' ) {
    $('#igna-1').slideToggle("fast", function() {
        $('#igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300, function() {
            $('#black, #igna, #igna-1').slideUp("fast", function() {
                $('#fatal, #igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.setTimeout()` to put some delay

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#contact-info').animate({right: 'toggle'});
    }, 500);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q3zc0ojy/3/)

Comment: However, the sub menu has to close first, then the first menu. This does happen when the whole menu is open and the user clicks on work again, then both menus close exactly how I need them too. This needs to happen when a user click on any other link.

Comment: @angela you should change you approach and make a generic function that should have common behavior, because as you add more elements thing are gona more  complex

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I make a generic function with common behaviour please?

Comment: Thanks for your advice @ozil, but I think I am not posing my question well enough, as I need the divs to slide back in reverse to how they slid in when any other link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Although I see that you have found your solution but as I had started coding the **TweenMax** version of it, I went on and finished it. The reason I am suggesting **GSAP** should be the go-to tool for animations for the web is not just because it is crazy [fast](https://greensock.com/js/speed.html), or easy to [jump-start](https://greensock.com/jump-start-js) or get [started](http://greensock.com/get-started-js) with, or makes some of the [coolest](https://greensock.com/drawSVG) [animation](https://greensock.com/SplitText) [effects](https://greensock.com/draggable) possible with few lines of code (I can [go on and on](https://greensock.com/products/)) ... but it is as intuitive as it can get.

Coming back to your animation, I have converted your animation solution into using [TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/timelinemax) / [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax) entirely, snippet of which is as follows:

```js
/*global TweenMax,TimelineMax,Power2,Power0*/
var getElementById=document.getElementById.bind(document);
var nameA=getElementById('name-a'),menu=getElementById('menu'),contact=getElementById('contact');
var contactInfo=getElementById('contact-info'),contactInfoAnchor=contactInfo.querySelector('a');
var igna=getElementById('igna'),ignaAnchor=igna.querySelector('a');
var ignaOne=getElementById('igna-1'),ignaOneAnchor=ignaOne.querySelector('a');
var ignaTwo=getElementById('igna-2'),ignaTwoAnchor=ignaTwo.querySelector('a');
var black=getElementById('black'),blackAnchor=black.querySelector('a');
var fatal=getElementById('fatal'),fatalAnchor=fatal.querySelector('a');
var bioLineOne=getElementById('bio-line-1'),bioLineOneParagraph=bioLineOne.querySelector('p');
var bioLineTwo=getElementById('bio-line-2'),bioLineTwoParagraph=bioLineTwo.querySelector('p');
var tlName=getTimeline(),tlContact=getTimeline(),tlWork=getTimeline(),tlIgnaTwo=getTimeline(),tlWorkIgnaTwoCombined=getTimeline();
var isTlNameDirectionForward=false,isTlContactDirectionForward=false,isTlWorkDirectionForward=false,isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward=false,reverseTimeScale=1;
var duration=.4,easeInOut=Power2.easeInOut,easeOut=Power2.easeOut,easeIn=Power2.easeIn,easeNone=Power0.easeNone;
function init(){
 setTlName();
 setTlContact();
 setTlWork();
 setTlIgnaTwo();
 setTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined();
 assignListeners();
}
function setTlName(){
 addParentDIVsToTimeline(tlName,[bioLineOne,bioLineTwo],['rect(10px 633px 50px 0px)','rect(10px 633px 50px 0px)']);
 tlName.fromTo(bioLineOneParagraph,duration,{x:-633},{x:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'x'},0).fromTo(bioLineTwoParagraph,duration,{y:-40},{y:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'y'},duration*.3);
}
function setTlContact(){
 addParentDIVsToTimeline(tlContact,[contactInfo],['rect(0px 120px 20px 0px)']);
 tlContact.fromTo(contactInfoAnchor,duration,{display:'block',x:150},{display:'block',x:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'display, x'},0);
}
function setTlWork(){
 var fromProps={display:'block',y:40},toProps={display:'block',y:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'display, y'};
 addParentDIVsToTimeline(tlWork,[fatal,igna,black],['rect(0px 120px 20px -90px)','rect(0px 120px 26px 0px)','rect(0px 120px 26px 0px)']);
 tlWork.fromTo(fatalAnchor,duration,{display:'block',x:-150},{display:'block',x:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'display, x'},0).fromTo(ignaAnchor,duration,fromProps,toProps,duration*.3).fromTo(blackAnchor,duration,fromProps,toProps,duration*.6);
}
function setTlIgnaTwo(){
 addParentDIVsToTimeline(tlIgnaTwo,[ignaTwo,ignaOne],['rect(0px 120px 20px -90px)','rect(0px 120px 26px 0px)']);
 tlIgnaTwo.fromTo(ignaTwoAnchor,duration,{display:'block',x:-150},{display:'block',x:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'display, x'},0).fromTo(ignaOneAnchor,duration,{display:'block',y:40},{display:'block',y:0,ease:easeOut,clearProps:'display, y'},duration*.3);
}
function setTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined(){
 tlWorkIgnaTwoCombined.to(tlIgnaTwo,duration,{progress:0,ease:easeNone},0).to(tlWork,tlWork.totalDuration(),{progress:0,ease:easeNone},duration*.3);
}
function assignListeners(){
 nameA.addEventListener('click',onNameAClicked,false);
 menu.addEventListener('click',onMenuClicked,false);
 contact.addEventListener('click',onContactClicked,false);
 igna.addEventListener('click',onIgnaClicked,false);
 ignaOneAnchor.addEventListener('click',playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined,false);
 ignaTwoAnchor.addEventListener('click',playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined,false);
 black.addEventListener('click',onMenuClicked,false);
 fatal.addEventListener('click',onMenuClicked,false);
}
function onNameAClicked(){
 isTlNameDirectionForward=!isTlNameDirectionForward;
 isTlNameDirectionForward?tlName.timeScale(1).play():tlName.timeScale(1).reverse();
 reverseTlContact();
 if(isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward){playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined();}else if(isTlWorkDirectionForward){reverseTlWork();}
}
function onMenuClicked(){
 isTlWorkDirectionForward=!isTlWorkDirectionForward;
 isTlWorkDirectionForward?tlWork.timeScale(1).play():tlWork.timeScale(1).reverse();
 reverseTlContact();
 reverseTlName();
 if(isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward){playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined();}
}
function onContactClicked(){
 isTlContactDirectionForward=!isTlContactDirectionForward;
 isTlContactDirectionForward?tlContact.timeScale(1).play():tlContact.timeScale(1).reverse();
 reverseTlName();
 if(isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward){playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined();}else if(isTlWorkDirectionForward){reverseTlWork();}
}
function onIgnaClicked(){
 isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward=!isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward;
 isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward?tlIgnaTwo.timeScale(1).play():tlIgnaTwo.timeScale(1).reverse();
}
function addParentDIVsToTimeline(tl,parents,clipRects){
 var length=parents.length;
 for(var i=0;i<length;i+=1){tl.fromTo(parents[i],duration,{display:'none',clip:clipRects[i]},{display:'block',clip:clipRects[i],ease:easeOut,clearProps:'clip'},duration*.3*i);}
}
function getTimeline(){return new TimelineMax({paused:true});}
function reverseTlContact(){
 if(isTlContactDirectionForward){
  isTlContactDirectionForward=false;
  tlContact.timeScale(reverseTimeScale).reverse();
 }
}
function reverseTlName(){
 if(isTlNameDirectionForward){
  isTlNameDirectionForward=false;
  tlName.timeScale(reverseTimeScale).reverse();
 }
}
function reverseTlWork(){
 isTlWorkDirectionForward=false;
 tlWork.timeScale(reverseTimeScale).reverse();
}
function playTlWorkIgnaTwoCombined(){
 isTlIgnaTwoDirectionForward=isTlWorkDirectionForward=false;
 tlWork.pause(tlWork.totalTime());
 tlIgnaTwo.pause(tlIgnaTwo.totalTime());
 tlWorkIgnaTwoCombined.pause(0).play();
}
//
init();
```

```css
#name-a {
 left: 38px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 38px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-1 {
 left: 150px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 35px;
 width: 633px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-1 p {
 color: #333333;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 21px;
 width: 552px;
}
#bio-line-2 {
 left: 150px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 38px;
 width: 633px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#bio-line-2 p {
 color: #333333;
 display: block;
 float: right;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 21px;
 width: 552px;
}
#menu {
 bottom: 34px;
 left: 38px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 4;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
#contact {
 bottom: 34px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 38px;
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
#contact-info {
 bottom: 34px;
 margin-right: 38px;
 position: fixed;
 right: 160px;
 text-transform: lowercase;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
#fatal {
 bottom: 34px;
 float: right;
 left: 135px;
 margin-left: 36px;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 z-index: 1;
}
#black {
 bottom: 61px;
 float: right;
 left: 171px;
 margin-bottom: 18px;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 z-index: 1;
}
#igna {
 bottom: 52px;
 float: right;
 left: 171px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 270px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#igna-1 {
 bottom: 72px;
 left: 404px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 162px;
 z-index: 1;
}
#igna-2 {
 bottom: 57px;
 left: 82px;
 margin-left: 321px;
 position: fixed;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 162px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.sub-menu {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="name-a"><a href="#">John Smith</a></div>
<div id="menu"><a href="#">Work</a></div>
<div id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
<div class="hidden" id="contact-info"><a href="#">conatct@foo.com</a></div>
<div class="hidden hover" id="black"><a href="#">item 1</a></div>
<div class="hidden hover" id="igna"><a href="#">item 2</a></div>
<div class="hidden hover" id="fatal"><a href="#">item 3</a></div>
<div class="hidden hover" id="igna-1"><a href="#">S/S <span id="ss">15</span></a></div>
<div class="hidden hover" id="igna-2"><a href="#">A/W 14</a></div>
<div id="bio-line-1" class="hidden"><p>holds a Master's Degree from the University of the Arts London</p></div>
<div id="bio-line-2" class="hidden"><p>and currently works foo bar.</p></div>
```

Hope you find it all useful in some way.

Further reading:

- [Sequence JavaScript Animations Like a Pro with GSAP's
  TimelineLite](http://greensock.com/sequence-video).
- [Understanding the Position Parameter](http://greensock.com/position-parameter).

P.S. The example above may not have done justice to the library. There may have been bugs in my code or the approach may seem overly complicated, but these shouldn't take away the credits from this GreenSock Animation Platform. Love this tool.

T